# Database backup bash working via ssh but not in cronjob

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, backup, cron

I've put together a script to backup my database on a shared host. The script is as follows:

```
mysqldump --databases [db1] [db2] | openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -pass file:/home/[user]/etc/.keys/.backup_key | gzip > /home/[user]/backup/$(date +%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S).gz
```

The database credentials are stored in a .cnf in /home/[user], and the encryption key in the key file shown in the script. When I run this script via SSH, everything works correctly and a backup file is created. However no files are created by the cronjob set to execute at the top of every day.

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Comment: Is the cronjob running as the same user? I've never tried running crons on my host. May try a small cron job which prints (or saves) the name of the user and group?

Comment: @jcoppens: Just tried this, the cron job runs as the same user as when accessing via ssh, where the command works.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to create the cron job under the correct user account.

```
crontab -u <username> -e
```

Also, escape the % with '\'.

```
mysqldump --databases [db1] [db2] | openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -pass file:/home/[user]/etc/.keys/.backup_key | gzip > /home/[user]/backup/$(date +\%Y:\%m:\%d:\%H:\%M:\%S).gz
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I worked out was appending to the start of the command: cd /home/[user]/ && {rest of command} as /home/[user]/ is where the mysql credentials were kept in a .cnf file which mysqldump required for the dump. I also escaped the '%' at the same time so perhaps that also helps. Thanks to @alex-atkinson for the escape tip.